# Oracle apex download blob file from collection

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I'm trying to download file from collection.
I looked through many forum, including here: [APEX: Download BLOB from temporary table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22940521/apex-download-blob-from-temporary-table)

But it is not working, I can't figure out why. no error is raised.
My PL/SQL code when pressing the button is:

```
DECLARE
  v_mime      VARCHAR2(255);
  v_length    NUMBER;
  v_file_name VARCHAR2(255);
  Lob_loc     BLOB;
BEGIN   
  SELECT c001, c004, blob001
  INTO   v_file_name, v_mime, Lob_loc
  FROM   apex_collections
  WHERE  collection_name = 'COLLECTION_DOCS' AND seq_id = :P113_SEQ;
  
  select sys.dbms_lob.getlength(Lob_loc) into v_length from dual;

  /* This raise shows me the correct values taken form the collection table
  raise_application_error (-20001,'
                           name:' || v_file_name || '
                           mime: ' || v_mime || '
                           length: ' || v_length || '
                           ');
  */
  
  sys.htp.init;
  sys.owa_util.mime_header(v_mime, FALSE);
  sys.htp.p('Content-length: ' || v_length);
  sys.htp.p('Content-Disposition:  attachment; filename="' || v_file_name || '"' );
  sys.owa_util.http_header_close;
  sys.wpg_docload.download_file( Lob_loc );
  apex_application.stop_apex_engine;

END;
```

Note that the values inside the commented section (when enabled) are showing the correct file name, mimetype and size when I press the button. That means that the the retrieval from the collection is working OK.

[image: document details]
[image: rendering section]
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I would try to use `sys.htp.p('Cache-Control: max-age=3600');` after the content disposition call.

Comment: Still not downloading :(

Comment: Where exactly did you put this code ?

Comment: @KoenLostrie I added pics of the download button, and the dynamic action that activates the PL/SQL code. It is all inside 'Modal Dialog' page that receive 'seq id' for the collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have posted is for a new http request to the server. If you put that code in a dynamic action, it will be executed in the current database session/rendered apex page and nothing happens.That is expected behaviour.

One way to solve this is is to create a separate page for download with page item PNN_SEQ. Put the code above in a before header page process on this new page. That original stack overflow post you are referring to mentions this as well: *This PL/SQL block is called 'on load before header'*

On your download button in the original page, put a redirect to url and pass the value for P113_SEQ. This will fire off a new request to the server of mimetype you need.

You can also do it in an application process as described here: https://joelkallman.blogspot.com/2014/03/yet-another-post-how-to-link-to.html

Comment: Thank you  very much it works! (I used the separate page). Only one thing, you wrote 'put a redirect to url', I guess you meant 'Redirect to page in this application'

Comment: Just an update: In the past month, something has changed, maybe related to browser update or something... but now the download window won't close, it just keep thinking and thinking (The download is still happening). So I had to change this method -> I copy the file from the collection into apex BLOB item, and download from there with simulating download click. If anyone have a fix for earlier bug I'll be happy to hear